# Async/Await and Redux Thunks: does calling 'dispatch' implicitly return a promise from the thunk?

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, async-await, redux-thunk

I'm trying to wrap my head around 'async/await', the fact that `async` functions always return `Promises` and using async functions with Redux Thunks --

I understand that `async` functions by definition always return a promise.  What if the last line of the async function is not an `await`, though?

```
const foo = async (y, z) => {
  await somethingElse()
  const x = y + z;
}
```

Does `foo` return a `Promise` that resolves to 'x' because that's on the last line?  If not, what `Promise` does it return?

So, when writing a thunk, I have a function like this

```
export const loadData = key => async (dispatch) => {
  const url = 'http://something.com/api/v1/get_key';
  const keyObj = { key };
  const method = 'POST';
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
  const body = JSON.stringify(keyObj);

  try {
    const res = await isofetch(url, { method, headers, body });
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
  } catch (e) {
    debug('error with fetch', e.toString());
  }
```

What does `loadData` return?  I believe that `dispatch` returns a`Promise`, so does `loadData` return that `Promise` implicitly?

Is there any difference if the last line were

```
return dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
```

?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: `async` function **always** return a Promise in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo = async (y, z) => {
  await somethingElse()
  const x = y + z;
}
```

Yes, this will return the promise. But it will be undefined as you haven't resolved it.

```
Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
```

Once await is finished, then foo will get the resolved data.

> I believe that dispatch returns a Promise

No, it doesn't. You'll need to return the value from async function so you'll get resolved data from promise. Thus, you'll use:

```
return dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
```

If you don't return the value in your async function, then you'll need to await from that promise to get the data:

```
await foo(y, z) // without return
foo(y, z) // with return
```

So technically, it's your opinion what to do with your async foo operation.

Comment: If `dispatch` doesn't return a promise, why are you awaiting it?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar OK, thanks.  Actually I think dispatch returns the action (`Returns
(Object†): The dispatched action` -- https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatch -- I don't know where I got the idea that it returns a `Promise`.  The json data is sent on to the reducers.  I don't understand what you mean by `await foo(y, z) // without return
foo(y, z) // with return`  -- the `await` can only be inside the async function, not outside, right?  If there's no return then only `undefined` will be returned, right?

Comment: @Bergi -- I'm awaiting, perhaps, an asynchronous API call ('somethingElse') -- I'll edit it...

Answer (score 1):

The function itself will return a promise.

```
const res = await isofetch(url, { method, headers, body });
const data = await res.json();
dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data));
```

Dispatch here will dispatch a json object response. You don't need to return it.

Comment: When you say 'dispatch a json object response.' you mean that the json response object will be sent out to the appropriate reducer, right?  I was just curious what was happening in this function, which, as you say, returns a promise....

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. You don't care much what the function will return in your case, you only care to dispatch a json object to the reducer, which is going to happen. I suggest using Redux Devtools if you're not, so you can easily track what is the payload of each action and much more.